# How did the derivative shift? (Turbojet Thrust Equation)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, drag, lift

While deriving the Turbojet Thrust Equation this is what the author does

$$F=m\cdot a$$

$$F=m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

$$F=\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}v$$

$$F= m^*\cdot v$$

(where $m^*$ is the mass rate flow)

What I don't understand in the above derivtion is that how did they **just** transform the **dv/dt** into  a **dm/dt**

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Do you have a citation for this derivation?

Comment: Ofcourse you don't understand it because it is mathematical nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't exactly speak for the derivation as you have laid it out here because it doesn't really make sense... perhaps there is additional text that sheds light on what the set of equations means.

However, let's look at what the thrust equation is saying. Newton's second law is often expressed as $F = ma$, but in reality Newton's second law says that the time rate of change of *momentum* is due to forces on the body:

$$ F = \frac{d}{dt}(mv) $$

and in the classical Newtonian mechanics sense of things where we talk about point particles or spheres or what have you, the mass is usually held constant and so we end up with $F = m\,dv/dt = ma$.

Back to the turbojet thrust equation. What we're interested in is the time rate of change of momentum due to the engine. We can use the product rule to say:

$$ F = \frac{dm}{dt} v + m \frac{dv}{dt} = \dot{m} v + m a$$

If we are at steady state in the reference frame of the engine, meaning we are not accelerating or decelerating, we're just cruising along at constant speed $v$, then the acceleration is zero and we're just left with:

$$ F = \dot{m} v $$

which is the thrust equation saying that an engine's thrust is to mass flow rate through it times the velocity of the exhaust.

Also note that this equation is for the *gross thrust* at steady state. To get the *net thrust* or *effective thrust*, you would need to account for the change in mass flow rate and velocity across the engine by subtracting off ram drag, [as in](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/turbth.html):

$$ F = \dot{m}_{\text{exhaust}} v_{\text{exhaust}} - \dot{m}_{\text{inlet}} v_{\text{inlet}} $$

It also assumes the inlet and exhaust pressures are the same, which is not always the case. The [generalized thrust equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/thrsteq.html) has an additional term to account for that situation.

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't understand in the above derivation is that how did they
> just transform the dv/dt into a dm/dt?

It's not possible. But it might have something to do with the following reasoning, where $p$ is the linear momentum:

$$p=mv$$

**Newton's Second Law:**

$$F=\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}(mv)}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
Apply product rule:

$$F=m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}+v\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$F=ma+\dot{m}v$$

Of course, in most problems $\dot{m}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gert could you be a gent and tell me in what all cases is m*a = 0 and m[dot]v is =/= 0? And how or why is m.a in the thrust equation = 0?

Comment: Hi. Obviously $ma=0$ for $\text{zero}$ acceleration, e.g. the plane (powered by the turbojet engine) is flying at constant $v$. And $\dot{m}v=0$ is when the turbojet isn't working (not ejecting any exhaust gases) because then $m=\text{constant}$.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry if my Q was dumb but I'm still in HS and this is for college exams I've to study first-year material on my own hence the doubt. Also, nice explanation thank you :)